# VB.NET iterate through class items saved to List Of(Class)

Tags: vb.net, list, class

I have a Public Class Field_Data

```
Public Class Field_Data

#Region "Location_v1"
    Public Property sample_name As String
    Public Property analysis_date As String
```

I can instantiate the class and add data to it for multiple subsets

```
  For iCol = 7 To LastCol
        Dim myFDData As New Field_Data
        myFDData.sample_name = wkbRep.Worksheets(0).Range(31, iCol).Value
        myFDData.analysis_date = wkbRep.Worksheets(0).Range(32, iCol).Value
```

I add each filled class to as List

```
Dim Summary_Data As New List Of(Field_Data)
```

Using

```
Summary_Data.Add(myFDData)
```

Fills the list

I then want to iterate through list to write summary file

```
For Each MyFieldItem as Field_Data In Summary_Data
```

Returns empty values

What am I doing wrong? TIL

Comment: You aren't showing us something or you are leaving out an important detail. I'm able to follow your steps and have it print the proper values. Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RPfEaV

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you are going wrong because yo didn't include all the code. See if this matches your pattern. I assume you are retrieving data from an Excel. That can be a bit tricky but you didn't provide the code. Separating the work into 2 methods may help you see where it is going wrong. Set a break point and step through observing the values of the variables.

```
Private Summary_Data As New List(Of Field_Data)

Private Sub AddDataToSummaryList()
    For iCol = 7 To LastCol
        Dim myFDData As New Field_Data
        myFDData.sample_name = wkbRep.Worksheets(0).Range(31, iCol).Value
        myFDData.analysis_date = wkbRep.Worksheets(0).Range(32, iCol).Value
        Summary_Data.Add(myFDData)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub WriteListToFile()
    For Each MyFieldItem As Field_Data In Summary_Data
        'Your code to write file here
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you've added all your things to the wrong list

Here's a simple example

```
Imports System
imports System.Collections.Generic
                
Public Module Module1

    Dim x as new List(of String)
    
    Public Sub Main()
        
        Dim x as new List(of String)
            
        x.Add("")
        
        HowMany()
    End Sub
    
    sub HowMany() 
        Console.Out.WriteLine(x.Count)
    end sub
    
End Module
```

You have a new List X at class level and you made another one also called X at a more local level. You filled the local one, then elsewhere used the class level one.

The code above prints 0 because nothing is ever added to the class level list